# is it possible to post facebook page wall using a cron job?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Please don't vote and flag this quest. Please.

I am is the admin of the page. How can I post to that page wall using php SDK.

Is it possible or not?
the following code is posting as I post the page. I want the page itself post things to the wall.

```
<?php
include_once("inc/facebook.php"); //include facebook SDK

######### edit details ##########
$appId = '1157979879888106'; //Facebook App ID
$appSecret = '86403d4061433e23a0ouo9ec46a1405'; // Facebook App Secret
$return_url = 'http://xxxx.com/site/test';  //return url (url to script)
$homeurl = 'http://xxxx.com/site/index';  //return to home
$fbPermissions = 'publish_stream,manage_pages';  //Required facebook permissions
##################################

$page_id = "447126725331764";

//Call Facebook API
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => $appId,
    'secret' => $appSecret
));

//$fbuser = $facebook->getUser();


$publish = $facebook->api('/'.$page_id.'/feed', 'post',
    array('access_token' => 'CAAQdLHAnOgoBAGAYZCIE09nfXaWZBXdMuwW5I379TjaWMZAQSUZCks9B4JfQyMXBEDN1CQZBaQJFeP44vWTGhic8AnkBgARge0AKJHIYgMdfDk16rq6ON496t0Phv6QtCmOR7t3wcybioNjxFkYctuN1ppDEBQdAObi6eIva0ZBTvAHJOWCSfcNicaVIZD',
        'message'=> "Hello boss",
        'from' => $appId,
        'to' => $page_id,
        'caption' => 'Caption',
        'name' => 'Name',
        'link' => 'http://www.example.com/',
        'picture' => 'http://www.phpgang.com/wp-content/themes/PHPGang_v2/img/logo.png',
        'description' => 'Hello boss'.' via demo.PHPGang.com'
    ));
?>
```

Comment: It is possible. What have you tried so far? Please do some research before asking for the possibilities.

Comment: It is not possible at all

Comment: @NishantGhodke Edited have a kind look pls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `publish_stream` is deprecated since many years. You really need to check out the [Facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/page/feed#publish), they state clearly that you need `publish_pages` and `manage_pages` to post "as Page".

That being said, that exact same question gets asked a LOT on Stackoverflow, so you can easily find a lot more information with the search function. In general, this is what you need to do:

- Authorize the user with `publish_pages` and `manage_pages`
- (Generate an Extended User Token)
- Get a Page Token with `/me/accounts`
- User that Page Token to post to the Page wall

More information about Access Tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/